# Searching for free downloadable Loop and Recording databases.

Tags: recording, atmosphere, sounds

Anyone know of any?

basically free beats etc but hopefully with some atmosphere recordings, like cities, crowds what have ya..

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked [Looperman](http://www.looperman.com/) for musical loops.  As far as non-musical, [The Freesound Project](http://freesound.org) has been my go to for anything I need for free, but I've generally had to make my own loops from their existing atmos.  With both sites you need to credit the original author.

Comment: +1 for Freesound.  Some of the stuff is hyper-cool.  If you're looking for specific effects it can be a bit frustrating.

Comment: And, on the flip side, sometimes you stumble across absolute jewels, usually when you've been searching other libraries for hours.

Answer (score 1):

check out http://www.soundjay.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/)?

Comment: Specifically, the advanced search options to choose downloadable items with cc license: http://soundcloud.com/tracks/search?q[type]=&q[duration]=&q[downloadable]=true&q[cc_licensed]=1&q[commercial]=true&q[derivative]=true&advanced=1

Answer (score 0):

The Sound Collectors' Club is not totally free (£20 annual membership fee) but once you've joined you can download as many recordings as you like for no further cost from a variety of different themed collections such as 'Wind' and 'Night and Day' atmoses from around the world.  The only requirement is that you have to contribute a recording of your own to a collection in order to be able to gain access to it.  In this way, we are gradually building a crowdsourced online sound FX library.

For more info, check out:

http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/